# Apache ProxyPass Root

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have setup apache fronting my services using the following example config.

/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/services.conf

```
<Location /A>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8082
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8082
</Location>

<Location /B>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8083
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8083
</Location>

<Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8084
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8084
</Location>
```

However adding `<Location />` stops all my other proxy pass's from working, I just get an error has occurred, can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Use LocationMatch with negative lookahead on the last one:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!(A|B)/?)">
    ProxyPass .....
</LocationMatch>
```

This will have the last one only proxypass if it is NOT /A or /B